# C#: Checking if an object exists in a list

Tags: c#, list, oop, nullreferenceexception

I have a Subject class and a Student class which contains a list of Subjects implemented as:

```
class Student
{
    // 1 Properties and Fields
    public List<Subject> Subjects;

    // 2 Constructor
    public Student()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }

    // 3 Methods
    public Subject SelectSubject(Subject subject)
    {
        if (Subjects.Contains(subject))
        {
            return subject;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the SelectSubject method, I want to pass in a subject and check if that variable exists in the Subjects class. However, I am getting a

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: Looks like the exception occours after a not shown call of `SelectSubject(...)`